# Is it practical to write to a global buffer without synchronization with OpenCL?

Tags: opencl

I'm considering an interesting problem in which it may be possible to increase performance beyond that of a typical program by allowing kernels to write their outputs to memory without performing any synchronization.

I'm computing the voxelization from a mesh, and it is not required for the voxels on the inside of the mesh to be filled. This makes the problem simpler.

I am hoping to apply the very simple algorithm where the kernel simply computes the voxels that intersect a triangle, and dispatch the kernel on each triangle of the mesh.

My current idea is to simply have the kernel write a value to the voxels that it computes as intersecting the triangle, without applying any synchronization. It matters not to me the count of the number of triangles that a particular voxel touches, I care only that I guarantee the identification of all voxels touching any triangle.

As such the question is can I expect this simple approach to "just work" or does there exist a possible race condition in which a voxel already marked as occupied may end up getting cleared out?

If the problem is possible, then would making the store atomic (and incurring a performance hit) resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [OpenCL 1.2 specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/opencl-1.2.pdf):

> 3.3.1 Memory Consistency
>
> OpenCL uses a relaxed consistency memory model; i.e. the state of memory visible to a work- item is not guaranteed to be consistent across the collection of work-items at all times. Within a work-item memory has load / store consistency. Local memory is consistent across work-items in a single work-group at a work-group barrier. Global memory is consistent across work-items in a single work-group at a work-group barrier, **but there are no guarantees of memory consistency between different work-groups executing a kernel**. Memory consistency for memory objects shared between enqueued commands is enforced at a synchronization point.

So if each work-item processes a single triangle, and updates the voxel-value of any voxel intersecting with that triangle, there is **no guarantee for the order of loads/stores from different work-items** (possible in different work-groups) on the voxel-values.

> As such the question is can I expect this simple approach to "just
>   work" or does there exist a possible race condition in which a voxel
>   already marked as occupied may end up getting cleared out?

Let's assume your voxel-values are 0-initialised, and an intersection is indicated by writing some non-zero value, and otherwise no write happens (i.e. never store a 0-value). Then all the writes on the voxel-value would change it to a non-zero value, and the order does not matter, as you are only interested in observing a non-zero value (not trying to count intersections or something).

TL;DR: It should work.

Answer (score -1):

AFAICT, everything written in noma's answer is correct, except the conclusion. In theory, it should work. In practice, it's likely not going to work.

The problem is that GPUs, like CPUs, work with memory through caches, and caches have cachelines. If you just want to write a single byte, the whole cacheline is still fetched, and *the whole cacheline is also stored back*. CU (compute units) have their own separate caches. So what happens if you're unlucky and two CUs decide, around the same time, to write "1" into bytes which are at different address but less than cacheline-bytes away ? both CUs will fetch the same cacheline from memory (or L2), write "1" at the correct place, and then flush it. But in memory, you end up with only one "1" - depending on whichever cacheline was flushed last.

you could avoid this problem by using a whole cacheline for every "1" value, but it's going to have a huge memory cost, and likely not be faster than atomics.

I'd try to find some efficient implementation of parallel hash table on GPU.

Comment: This was the situation that I was expecting to encounter, but did not know enough about the specific architectural mechanism that would produce it. Thanks. A parallel hash table sounds like too much abstraction for the requirement. I should be fine if I just do atomic writes, yes?

Comment: Assuming the caches would work like that, the same pattern could happen on a normal ND-Range kernel, where each work-item writes one element of a result array, if the array elements aren't a multiple of the cache-line size (typically 64 byte). Thanks to [cache coherency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence), e.g. implemented using [MESI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol), the worst that will happen is [false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing), i.e. a performance degradation.

Comment: Steven: yeah atomics should work.

@noma: as for ND-Range kernel, yes you're right, it could happen.

As for cache coherency, i'm aware there are protocols, but AFAICT in GPU they're not always used. See what nvidia has to say about it:

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/gpu-coherence-problem/84153

"L1 caches on a GPU are not in any way guaranteed to be coherent with each other, and there is no coherence mechanism to make it so."

Comment: Well, one thing that bothers me (which your discussion appears to be about, but which I am not able to fully grok) is that if even this most basic of situations could result in undefined behavior based on cache race conditions, then how could any remotely sophisticated algorithm be expected to function properly? the answer would ostensibly be to use locks/synchronization. But then, under what situations would we be able not to use them?

Comment: Besides, isn't the purpose of cache to speed things up, and never to potentially introduce unexpected behavior (aside from performance impact)? Thinking about this more in relation to what I meant in my first comment, I expected to need to do some locking to deal with cache locality issues to fine-tune performance, but the concept of cache details leading to undefined/nondeterministic algorithm behavior (for such basic algorithms) sounds problematic for the memory model itself.

Comment: With respect to NVIDIA GPUs, the claims made in this answer (e.g. the italicized text, and other claims) are not correct.  The quoted text from the nvidia developer forums in the comments does not support these conclusions.  If the hazard suggested in this answer were real, it would be a violation of the C++ memory model, amongst possibly other violations.